# I am trying to make and ajax call to my django backend

Tags: html, ajax, django

I have ths code tyng to make a call to my django backed using ajax
but it gives me this error: **Reverse for 'delete_skill' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['jobs/delete_skill/(?P[0-9]+)$']**

```
<a href="{% url 'freelance:delete_skill' id_number %}"
                       class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_skill"
                            style="padding:0px; margin:0px; background:grey;
                             color:red; border:0px;" id="{{skill.id}}"></a>
            </span>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                   $(".delete_skill").click(function(){
                var id_number = this.id;
                alert(id_number);
                $.ajax({
                   type: 'DELETE',
                   url: "{% url 'freelance:delete_skill' id_number %}",
                   dataType: "json",
                   data: 'identifier='+id_number, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}
                   success: function(){
                      if(data) {alert("Success! skill has been deleted")}
        });

     });
```

});
my url is like this

```
url(r'^delete_skill/(?P<identifier>[0-9]+)$', views.delete_skill, name='delete_skill'),
```

any help on what is going on or what I should add please

Comment: Well it looks like your variable `id_number` either does *not* exists, or is the empty string.

Comment: but alerting the string removing the ajax code works just fine

Comment: Note that there is a `{% url` in the AJAX part.

Comment: yea so you mean that the id will not be loaded? tell me how I should write

Comment: I think you are confusing *front*-end with *back*-end. Django can only handle the backend. So it renders a page, after that the `{% url .. %}` is gone. So you will need to resolve this then in JavaScript, which makes it quite cumbersome. There is no straightforward way to do this in general, since if you change the url, then that part needs to change too. I would advice to make a `delete_skill` function, where you pass the `id` as a `POST` parameter.

Comment: I really don't get this. I need to make a javascript function with delete_skill?

Comment: delete skill as a parameter? or a django view

Comment: please if I can get and edited piece of the code I will appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to help you move forward, here a principle that I use:

1. Create data-* attribute for href such as data-href. You can read more about data-* attributes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

   ```
   <a href="#" data-href="{% url 'freelance:delete_skill' skill.id %}" 
     class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_skill" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;
     background:grey; color:red; border:0px;" id="{{skill.id}}"></a>
   ```
2. You can access this data-href attribute in javascript with `getAttribute()` or via dataset property. Below is jQuery example since you're using jQuery already.

   ```
   $(".delete_skill").click(function() {
       var url = $(this).attr("data-href");
       $.ajax({
           type: "DELETE",
           url: url,
           dataType: "json",
           data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
           success: function(data){
               if(data) {
                   alert("Success! skill has been deleted");
               }
           }
        });
   });
   ```

This way your code won't break when you change urls.

Comment: this is great I just could not figure this out now I know it was the url giving me the error. thanks for this only that I am now getting this (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /jobs/
 but is a good progress coz now it can reach the backend

Comment: Check if data is even posted to backend. I know there was a jQuery bug some time ago when data wasn't posted along with delete request. You can go around that by including CSRF token in ajax header by following instructions in [Django documentation on CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/).